# EXECUTE AS does not appear to be changing security context

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have legacy code that still makes use of xp_cmdshell calls.  When we migrated to SQL Server 2008, we created a stored procedure that used code after the following pattern:

```
EXECUTE AS 'DOMAIN\ID2'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command
REVERT
```

When I pass in WHOAMI as the command, what it shows is not the 'DOMAIN\ID2', but rather the ID of the service account that SQL Server is running under (i.e. 'DOMAIN\ID1').  Should it not be returning 'DOMAIN\ID2' as it's supposedly running unders a different security context?  If so, any idea why it would not be changing context?  This process was created by another dev who is now long gone and I'm not really familiar with security and impersonation as I probably should be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wouldn't be nice to find a tool that allows you to impersonate to Windows a user **without knowing the password**? Every intern could impersonate the CFO and withdraw millions from the bank... The possibilities!

No, `EXECUTE AS` is changing the security context **exclusively** with regard to access SQL Server objects (tables, procedures etc). By no means will (or even can, for the matter) be able to change the real NT execution context for the process or for processes launched by SQL Server.

Update

I obviously forgot to add the actual useful piece of information: there *is* a way to make `xp_cmdshell` use a specific credential, provided you do create such a [credential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189522.aspx) in SQL Server:

```
create credential [##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##] 
   with identity = 'DOMAIN\ID2',
   secret = '<ID2 password>';
```

The key difference is that you are very explicitly giving the password here to SQL Server. Now SQL Server will use this credential 'proxy' whenever faced with calling `xp_cmdshell` from a SQL login context or from a EXECUTE AS context.

You can also associate a credential with a login for 'generic' access to resources outside SQL Server (eg. accessing a network share):

> A credential is a record that contains the authentication information
>   that is required to connect to a resource outside SQL Server. Most
>   credentials include a Windows user and password.

Comment: Ah, then I have misunderstood how it was working.  So if I understand correctly, xp_cmdshell was probably limited to only allow DOMAIN\ID2 to execute it, preventing other user IDs from executing it unless that ID has been given rights to impersonate the ID2.  I'm really growing to love MSFT security setups... :|

Comment: It works like this: while you're under EXECUTE AS, *whithin th realm of SQL Server you *are* DOMAIN\ID2*. But, even under EXECUTE AS, as soon as you leave SQL Server the truth is revealed: you are again ID1. Basically SQL Server cannot tell Windows 'this is ID2, trust me' because had such API exist, it would quickly be abused as I pointed out. Windows trust only one proof to recognize ID2: present the password when challenged.